# Amazon Login to Pay Code issues

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-mws

Working with amazon login and pay, i have successfully made the code sample work, but i am now stuck at two places one such is `onAddressSelect` and `onPaymentSelect`

Both have as per docs, need to call the API to update the address if we choose something else from the delivery address and same applies to the `onpaymentSelect`, but i cannot find any kind of sample information of that, all i find is documentation as to how we have to do it, by reading i managed something like this but it throws error

```
onAddressSelect:function(orderReference) {
                orderReference.getAmazonOrderReferenceId();
            },

onPaymentSelect: function (orderReference) {
            },
```

i hope my question makes sense but i am not sure how should i made it working

Comment: *"but it throws error"*  Should we try to guess at the error you see?  Perhaps you'll edit that into the question. You mentioned documentation more than once, but you haven't provided any links to what you are reading.  Please help us help you by editing the question to provide as much relevant information and context as possible.

Comment: this is the error i get `TypeError: orderReference.getAmazonOrderReferenceId is not a function[Learn More]`

Comment: any update on this?

Comment: Please consider adding links to relevant documentation.

Comment: i m following this `https://github.com/amzn/login-and-pay-with-amazon-sdk-samples`

Comment: i think i added the code where i am following from, so from here we need to think how we can fix it

Comment: Same issue here